# How to make a formula in one cell only run when another cell has a content

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Hi I am using 2013 excel and have a formula in W269:
`=product(u269,v269)+50`

However I need this formula to run only when T269 contains a value (text not a number).

Here's some more details in case someone can offer a different solution:

```
T269= employee names
U269= pay rate
V269= hours worked
W269= total pay for a given day
50= $50 per diem each day an employee works.
```

The problem is when the employee doesn't work (and therefore doesn't get per diem) this formula will still erroneously generate 50 in W269 even though there was no employee in T269. This creates an erroneous total in w313. I would like excel to automatically add perdiem when an employee works and omit it when an employee doesn't work.

Ideas?...other than stop paying my employees perdiem :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a formula only 'run' under a condition. but you can easily make a formula calculate something different under a condition. Here, that could be:

=IF(T269="","",U269*V269+50)

This will test if T269 is blank, and if so, put blank (nothing) in W269 too; if T269 has a value, it will calculate your product.

Comment: that generates this formula error: check your parentheses,arguments, and references to other sheets. If you're not writing a formula, type a single quotation mark (') before any equal (=), minus (-) or @ signs.

Comment: sorry, I used semicolons instead of comma as this is my separator. I'll change it.

Comment: Tested with the commas instead of semi colons and it works! Thank you!

Comment: @JasonHorsley: if this answer solves your problem, than please accept it

Comment: It does. How do I accept it?

Comment: on the left of the answer, where there are up and down arrows, there should be a check to select answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(TYPE(T269)=2,product(u269,v269)+50,0)
```

This will calculate the per diem if T269 contains text, and return 0 otherwise. If you omit the final `,0` it will return the value `FALSE`.